# Is there a way to access specific attributes of html tags using Java/JSoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

For example, the code

```
Elements linksOnPage = htmlDocument.select("a[href]");
```

will return all  tags with an href attribute. But I want `<a>` tags where there is an attribute called *title* and it is equal to 'XXX'. Also, I want all `<span>` tags that have a *title* attribute equal to 'XXX' and furthermore, want the actual text value is inside that span tag.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: you can check if `linksOnPage.attr("title")` is equal to `XXX`

Comment: Awesome this works well for getting the values of the attributes, thank you! But still need to know how to get a value within the tag. For example I have <span title='XXX'>YYY</span>, what method returns YYY?

Comment: I have added an answer with all details !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to [this documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html):

You can select  which tags is `XXX` by: 
`htmlDocument.select("a[title="+XXX+"]");`

For data inside a tag: `tag.text()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `a[title=XXX]`, same for `span[title=XXX]`.

If you want to find them in one `select(..)` query, you can group multiple selectors by separating them with comma like

```
Elements linksOnPage = htmlDocument.select("a[title=XXX], span[title=XXX]");
```

If you want to get text which will be generated by selected tags you can call [`text()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text--) method on them.

You can find more info about selectors at official tutorial: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Answer (score 1):

For checking if attribute matches `XXX` you can check if `linksOnPage.attr("title")` is equal to `XXX`. The body of the span tags can be extracted using the [text()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html#text-java.lang.String-) function in jsoup and you can get the entire tags from [outerHtml()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#outerHtml--) function